# Range.Consolidate in Excel: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error"

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am having issues getting this to work for some reason, to the extent my hair is turning grey.
There is some data on sheet 'Test' that I am trying to consolidate on sheet 'finaldata'. Here's a screenshot of data:

[image: screenshot of data]

```vb
Sub ConsolidateData()
    Dim finalDataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim testSheet As Worksheet
    Dim finalDataRange As Range
    Dim testRange As Range
        
    ' Set references to the worksheets
    Set finalDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("finaldata")
    Set testSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    
    ' Set the range to consolidate in the finaldata sheet
    Set finalDataRange = finalDataSheet.Range("A1")
    
    ' Set the range to consolidate from the Test sheet
    Set testRange = testSheet.Range("A:P")
    
    ' Consolidate the data
    finalDataRange.Consolidate Sources:=Array(testRange.Address), Function:=xlSum, LeftColumn:=True
End Sub
```

I figured out the problem is in the `Sources:=Array(testRange.Address)` bit, but I can't really figure out what it is.

Hope anyone can help and has an inkling of what I am doing wrong. (I tried asking the wife, but all I got was an endless stream of non-relevant issues).

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: I don't think that [Consolidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.consolidate) will do what you expect. Why don't you show us the *finaldata* sheet before and after the 'consolidation'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.consolidate) state:

> The sources of the consolidation as an array of text reference strings in R1C1-style notation. The references must include the full path of sheets to be consolidated.

Try this (**not tested**):

```vb
Sub ConsolidateData()
    Dim finalDataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim testSheet As Worksheet
    Dim finalDataRange As Range
    Dim testRange As Range
        
    ' Set references to the worksheets
    Set finalDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("finaldata")
    Set testSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    
    ' Set the range to consolidate in the finaldata sheet
    Set finalDataRange = finalDataSheet.Range("A1")
    
    ' Set the range to consolidate from the Test sheet
    Set testRange = testSheet.Range("A:P")
    
    ' Consolidate the data
    finalDataRange.Consolidate _
            Sources:=Array(testSheet.Name & "!" & testRange.Address(, , xlR1C1), _
            Function:=xlSum, _
            LeftColumn:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you both! Clearly you are the smart ones! You have my gratitude and appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

"The sources of the consolidation as an array of text reference strings in R1C1-style notation. The references must include the full path of sheets to be consolidated."

```
....
finalDataRange.Consolidate Sources:=Array(testSheet.Name & "!" & testRange.Address(0, 0, xlR1C1, False, testSheet.Range("A1"))), Function:=xlSum, LeftColumn:=True
....
```